# MySQLのエラー「ステートメントの開始があるべきです」「#1064 - SQL構文エラー」

Tags: mysql

さくらサーバーで以下が出てしまい、取り込みができません。

```
エラー
静的解析:

解析中に 3 個のエラーが見つかりました。

ステートメントの開始があるべきです。 (near "be" at position 0)
ステートメントの開始があるべきです。 (near "used" at position 3)
認識されないステートメント形式。 (near "enable" at position 13)
SQL クエリ:

be used. --enable-cleartext-plugin Enable/disable the clear text authentication plugin. -e, --execute=name Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and his

MySQL のメッセージ: ドキュメント

#1064 - SQL構文エラーです。バージョンに対応するマニュアルを参照して正しい構文を確認してください。 : 'be used.
  --enable-cleartext-plugin
                      Enable/disable the c' 付近 1 行目
```

Comment: 何をしていて、どういうときにこのエラーが出たのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
結論、新規サーバーを立てました。

しかし、原因は、MySqlのデータバックアップを取るためのコマンドが誤っていたようです。

×mysqldump -u root c9 >db_backup.sql　
〇mysqldump -u root -p -h localhost c9 > db_backup.sql

envファイルのＰＡＳＳＷＯＲＤを設定した場合には、mysqldump -u root -p -h localhost c9 > db_backup.sql　でコマンドをうち、passwordを聞かれるので、打つ必要がありました。

DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root